# PayPal Transactions Under Review and REST API shows INVALID_RESOURCE_ID

Tags: node.js, rest, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I badly need help, I am stuck on this for almost 1 week now and I have no one to help me.

1. I have sandbox account, so I purchased through buyers test account, the transaction on buyers account said it was complete, however, on sellers account, transaction is tag as "under review", Is that considered completed?
2. Are payments with status under review not going to show up on payment list? because I pulled payment list using Paypal API, I get count= 0,but when I check payments for facilitators PayPal account there are payments under review.
3. When I try to get details of a sale with its transaction Id, I always get. this kind of error:

   {
         "name": "INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
         "message": "The requested resource ID was not found",
         "information_link":          "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INVALID_RESOURCE_ID",
         "debug_id": "d8b00ac574f4"
   }

but I am pretty sure that the transaction Id is correct as I confirmed it in the dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) This could happen if you have enabled "Payment Review" in your developer.paypal.com->sandbox accounts->Payment Review->On.

2) Only completed Sale transactions show up in [REST Sale API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#look-up-a-sale)

3)Since the transaction is not complete, you will get "Invalid Resouce ID" internally means "TRANSACTION_ID_DOES_NOT_EXIST"

Comment: Vimalnath can you tell about this https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/issues/330